# Is this problem wrong? I keep getting $y = ±(\sqrt{c-x^4})/x$ which is not possible as $x = 0$ and $y = 2$. Am I wrong?

Tags: derivatives, homogeneous-equation

Find the particular solution that satisfies the initial condition:
Differential Equation:

$$(2x^2+y^2)dx+xydy=0$$

Initial Condition:

$$y(0) = 2$$

I solved it and got

$$y = ±(\sqrt{c-x^4})/x$$

which is undefined for $x = 0$.

Comment: There is indeed no solution of the form $y(x)$.  However, there is a local solution $x(y)=0$.